# Dataset of historical economic forecasts

Tags: data-request, economics, finance

Where could I get a dataset of economic forecasts made over years? For instance, the history of predictions for GDP, current accounts, and other key national variables by the World Bank and IMF? Or similar information from governments?

Answer (score 3):

The World Bank provides an excellent [overview](http://www.worldbank.org/en/publication/global-economic-prospects) and [summary](http://www.worldbank.org/en/publication/global-economic-prospects/summary-table), as well as detailed [current](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/views/variableselection/selectvariables.aspx?source=global-economic-prospects) and [historical](http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/world-development-indicators) data.

Additionally:

- You can get information from individual [government open data portals](https://www.data.gov/open-gov/) (scroll to bottom), but it's inconsistently formatted and may not be available from all governments.
  Oxford Economics provides country economic forecasts.  There's summary information [here](http://www.oxfordeconomics.com/forecasts-and-models/countries/briefings-and-outlook/country-economic-forecasts/overview), and an archive of free open data [here](http://www.oxfordeconomics.com/archive). (Note that there is a fee to get access to all their data, although you can get a free trial.)
- The International Monetary Fund has a [summary](http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2014/01/weodata/index.aspx) of GDP and [detailed data](http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2014/01/weodata/weoselgr.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in

Domenico Giannone, Jérôme Henry, Magdalena Lalik and Michele Modugno 2010), An area-wide real-time database for the euro area. ECB Working Paper Series No 1145 / January 2010 available at http://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1145.pdf.

There are some details of the data base on the EABCN web site and data can be downloaded by non EABCN members at https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/shared/download/stats/sdw/docu/databases/rtdb/rtdb_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I will throw in a secondary source:

http://apps.resourcegovernance.org/forecast-tracker/

On this site you can find, filter and download (+ visualize) aggregated data from multiple years of IMF World Economic Outlook forecasts (most recent [here](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2018/02/weodata/index.aspx)). The data is available on the IMF site, but not aggregated across years (so you have to download forecasts from 2015 in one file, 2016 in another, etc.).

The WEO covers nearly all countries, dozens of economic indicators as well as dozens of commodity price forecasts, all available on the site. Data is updated semi-annually, with the release of new data by the IMF.

[disclosure: I created this app]